# php include or require contents of a variable, not a file

Tags: php, require

I'm looking for a way to include or require the content of a variable, instead of a file.

Normally, one can require/include a php function file with either of these:

```
require_once('my1stphpfunctionfile.php')
include('my2ndphpfunctionfile.php');
```

Suppose I wanted to do something like this:

```
$contentOf1stFFile = file_get_contents('/tmp/my1stphpfunctionfile.php');

$contentOf2ndFFile = file_get_contents('/tmp/my2ndphpfunctionfile.php');

require_once($contentOf1stFFile);
require_once($contentOf2ndFFile);
```

Now, in the above example, I have the actual function files which I am loading into variables.  In the real world scenario I'm actually dealing with, the php code in the function files are not stored in files.  They're in variables.  So I'm looking for a way to treat those variables as include/require treats the function files.

I'm new to php so please forgive these questions if you find them foolish.  What I'm attempting to do here does not appear to be possible.  What I ended up doing was using `eval` which I'm told is very dangerous and should be avoided:

```
eval("?>$contentOf1stFFile");
eval("?>$contentOf2ndFFile");
```

**Content of $contentOf1stFFile:**

```
# class_lookup.php
<?php

class Lookup_whois {
  // Domain name which we want to lookup
  var $domain;
  // TLD for above domain, eg. 'com', 'net', etc...
  var $tld;
  // Array which contains information needed to parse the whois server response
  var $tld_params;
  // Sets to error code if something fails
  var $error_code;
  // Sets user-friendly error message if something goes wrong
  var $error_message;
  // For internal use mainly - raw response from the whois server
  var $whois_raw_output;

  function Lookup_whois($domain, $tld, $tld_params) {
    $this->domain     = $domain;
    $this->tld        = $tld;  
    $this->tld_params = $tld_params;
  }

  function check_domain_spelling() {
    if (preg_match("/^([A-Za-z0-9]+(\-?[A-za-z0-9]*)){2,63}$/", $this->domain)) {
                        return true;
                } else {
                        return false;
                }
  }

  function get_whois_output() {
    if (isset($this->tld_params[$this->tld]['parameter'])) {
      $query = $this->tld_params[$this->tld]['parameter'].$this->domain.'.'.$this->tld; 
    } else {
      $query = $this->domain.'.'.$this->tld; 
    }
    $server = $this->tld_params[$this->tld]['whois'];
    if (!$this->check_domain_spelling()) {
      $this->error_message = 'Domain name is not correct, check spelling. Only numbers, letters and hyphens are allowed';
      return false;
    }
    if (!$server) {
      $this->error_message = 'Whois server name is empty, please check the config file';
      return false;
    }
    $output = array(); 
    $fp = fsockopen($server, 43, $errno, $errstr, 30); 
    if(!$fp) {
      $this->error_code    = $errno;
      $this->error_message = $errstr;
      fclose($fp);
      return false; 
    } else { 
      sleep(2);
      fputs($fp, $query . "\n"); 
      while(!feof($fp)) { 
        $output[] = fgets($fp, 128); 
      }
      fclose($fp);
      $this->whois_raw_output = $output;
      return true; 
    } 
  }

  function parse_whois_data() {
    if (!is_array($this->whois_raw_output) && Count($this->whois_raw_output) < 1) {
      $this->error_message = 'No output to parse... Get data first';
      return false;
    }
    $wait_for = 0;
    $result = array();
    $result['domain'] = $this->domain.'.'.$this->tld;
    foreach ($this->whois_raw_output as $line) {
      #if (ereg($this->tld_params[$this->tld]['wait_for'], $line)) {
      if (preg_match($this->tld_params[$this->tld]['wait_for'],$line)) {
        $wait_for = 1;
      }
      if ($wait_for == 1) {
        foreach ($this->tld_params[$this->tld]['info'] as $key => $value) {
          $regs = '';
          if (ereg($value.'(.*)', $line, $regs)) {
            if (key_exists($key, $result)) {
              if (!is_array($result[$key])) {
                $result[$key] = array($result[$key]);
              }
              $result[$key][] = trim($regs[1]);
            } else {
              $result[$key] = trim($regs[1]);
              $i = 1;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return $result;  
  }

}

?>
```

Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: Could you further describe your use case. Why are you executing php that isn't stored in a file? Where does the php come from?

Comment: Please post content of /tmp/my1stphpfunctionfile.php

Comment: Well, `eval()` is pretty much the same as `include()`. And "… which I'm told is very dangerous and should be avoided" is somewhat useless advise without rationale and context.

Comment: @AndreaManzi I have added the code to my post, as requested.

Comment: @user2831586 we need to know where the PHP comes from. If it comes from an outside source (like an exposed HTTP POST endpoint), then you should NEVER use eval. Why do you have it in a variable instead of via `include`?

Comment: Why can't you just use include() or require() here as normal? You haven't really explained a limitation which would prevent that. You say `the php code in the function files are not stored in files. They're in variables` but what do you actually mean by that? How does the data get into the variables? If it's just by loading the content of a file as per your example code, then you could just use include(), surely?? Have I missed an important point?

Answer (score 0):

No there are no other alternatives.

In terms of security there is no difference if you `include()` a file or `eval()` the content. It depends on the context. As long as you only run your own code there is nothing "dangerous".